# Divide two metrics in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have two metrics, scratched from telegraf.

first metric

`vsphere_host_mem_active_average{esxhostname=~"esx1"}`

gives one value

```
vsphere_host_mem_active_average{clustername="BCH1",collector="telegraf",dcname="DC",esxhostname="esx1",host="vm01",hostname="hostname1",instance="localhost:9273",job="vSphere",moid="host-78563",source="esx1",type="vmware",vcenter="vmc"}    17763152
```

second one

`vsphere_vm_mem_granted_average{esxhostname=~"esx1"})`

gives several with different labels

1.

```
vsphere_vm_mem_granted_average{clustername="BCH1",dcname="DC",esxhostname="esx1",guest="debian9_64",host="vm01",moid="vm-79139",source="vm01",uuid="42244f7b-abeb-92be-3e67-af19a9d8dfbd",vcenter="vmc",vmname="vm01"} 4.19418e+06
```

2.

```
vsphere_vm_mem_granted_average{clustername="BCH1",dcname="DC",esxhostname="esx1",guest="debian9_64",host="vm01",moid="vm-79146",source="vm01",uuid="4224ed0c-f306-202c-fc99-35e48fe52370",vcenter="vmc",vmname="vm02"} 8.377904e+06
```

is that possible to get result of first value divided by second values for each of set of labels?

Comment: As mentioned in [PromQL documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators) you can just divide two instant vectors and resulting vector will contain result of division for each entries with same set of label values. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 17):

Prometheus applies arithmetic operators such as `/`, `-`, `+`, `*` individually per each pair of time series with identical set of labels (ignoring metric name) on both sides of the operator. If there are no pairs of time series with identical labels, then Prometheus returns nothing. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) for more details. This behavior can be augmented by applying `on()`, `ignoring()`, `group_left()` and `group_right()` modifiers - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches).

So, if you need to divide a single time series by two other time series with distinct set of labels, then the following PromQL query should work:

```
vsphere_host_mem_active_average{esxhostname=~"esx1"}
  / on() group_right()
vsphere_vm_mem_granted_average{esxhostname=~"esx1"}
```

The `on()` modifier instructs Prometheus to limit the set of labels, which are used to find pairs of time series with identical labels on the left and the right side of `/` operator, to an empty set. The empty list at `on()` modifier automatically matches any time series on the left side of `/` operator to any time series on the right side of `/` operator.

The `group_right()` modifier instructs Prometheus to divide a single time series on the left side of `/` operator individually to every time series on the right side of `/` operator. The resulting time series contain labels from the right side time series. Additional labels from time series on the left side can be added to result by enumerating them inside `group_right()` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am not interpreting the question quite right, but if you want to  divide 2 metrics together, you simply use the '/' operator in your PromQL, documented here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/

As an example using your above values, the query you would use is something like:

```
(vsphere_host_mem_active_average{clustername="BCH1",collector="telegraf",dcname="DC",esxhostname="esx1",host="vm01",hostname="hostname1",instance="localhost:9273",job="vSphere",moid="host-78563",source="esx1",type="vmware",vcenter="vmc"}/vsphere_vm_mem_granted_average{clustername="BCH1",dcname="DC",esxhostname="esx1",guest="debian9_64",host="vm01",moid="vm-79139",source="vm01",uuid="42244f7b-abeb-92be-3e67-af19a9d8dfbd",vcenter="vmc",vmname="vm01"})
```

Comment: I think the question is more specifically asking how to do this without knowing all possible label values ahead of time.